# require() of ES Module \node_modules\string-width\index.js from \node_modules\wide-align\align.js not supported

Tags: yarnpkg, require, commonjs, notsupportedexception, esmodules

> `#11 44.55  ERROR  require() of ES Module /app/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /app/node_modules/wide-align/align.js not supported.
> #11 44.55 Instead change the require of index.js in /app/node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
> #11 44.55
> #11 44.55   Instead change the require of index.js in node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
> #11 44.55   at Object. (node_modules/wide-align/align.js:2:19)

#11 44.55  ERROR  require() of ES Module /app/node_modules/string-width/index.js from /app/node_modules/wide-align/align.js not supported.
#11 44.55 Instead change the require of index.js in /app/node_modules/wide-align/align.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
#11 44.55
#11 44.57 error Command failed with exit code 1.
#11 44.57 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for `

---

The issue here seems to be caused by your package manager.

Now I refresh the lock-file multiple times. Take the Stackblitz - I refresh the lockfile there, and it works, but then I copy that lockfile locally and the issue persists there, while I refresh locally (and small chances it doesn't help) and copy to Stackblitz, then the container fails.

The actual version of string-width installed by yarn is v5 which seems to be incompatible with wide-align.
I'm afraid this isn't a Nuxt issue we can resolve.

although using the resolution, removing the yarn.lock and node_modules folder, it worked, even though it warned against an incompatibility between requested versions.

wide-align, which is used by npmlog, which is used by vite, eventually, forces the use of string-width<5, which from what I understand, was a dependency that yarn failed to comply with, causing the error.

from wide-align package.json:

`"//": "But not version 5 of string-width, as that's ESM only",   "dependencies": {     "string-width": "^1.0.2 || 2 || 3 || 4"`

Again, using the resolutions seems to be working, as long as you don't have a breaking dependency with the string-width ^5, it should be fine, but it can be really annoying. Wide-align has been inactive for over 2 years now, I doubt we will have a fix from them anytime soon. I might make a PR later to fix it

Answer (score 3):

Add this line in Your Package.json

"resolutions": {     "string-width": "4.2.3"  }

OR

"resolutions": {     "jackspeak": "2.1.1"  }

And Do this

Remove node_modules folder and yarn.lock package.lock files.
Run npm/yarn install.